# How to identify a web browser control instance called for window.external.method from inside this method?

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, controls, webbrowser-control

May I ask you for some help ?

I have a set of web-browser controls on a Form.
All web-browser are set to webBrowser.ObjectForScripting = this;
so all script calls are managed in the code of the form.

in the code I have let say :

```
public void Method1(string title)
{
     WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)some-object;
     MessageBox.Show(title + wb.Url.ToString());
}
```

How to get web-browser instance(some-object) that called for this method if it is called from one of the web-browser controls via JavaScript:

```
<script>
   window.external.Method1('Hello');
</script>
```

Thank you !!

Comment: Maybe, using a List of a specialized class to which you pass the WebBrowser instance it has to handle in its contructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some common options:

1. Usually, it's caller responsibility to introduce itself to the callee.
2. When only one caller can call, callee knows it's caller.

**Example 1 - Caller introduce itself**

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var txt =
        @"<html>" +
        @"<body>" +
        @"<a href=""#"" " +
            @"onclick=""window.external.Method1(this, 'Hello');"">" +
            @"Click here.</a>" +
        @"</body>" +
        @"</html>";
        webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
        webBrowser2.ObjectForScripting = this;
        webBrowser1.DocumentText = txt;
        webBrowser2.DocumentText = txt;
        webBrowser1.Document.Window.Name = webBrowser1.Name;
        webBrowser2.Document.Window.Name = webBrowser2.Name;
    }
    public void Method1(object sender, string s)
    {
        //sender is the anchor element
        dynamic window = ((dynamic)((dynamic)sender).document).defaultView;
        var windowName = window.Name;
        var control = this.Controls.Find(windowName, true);
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```

**Example 2 - Callee Knows the Caller**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txt =
    @"<html>" +
    @"<body>" +
    @"<a href=""#"" " +
        @"onclick=""window.external.Method1('Hello');"">" +
        @"Click here.</a>" +
    @"</body>" +
    @"</html>";
    webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptingObject(webBrowser1);
    webBrowser2.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptingObject(webBrowser2);
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = txt;
    webBrowser2.DocumentText = txt;
}
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ScriptingObject
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser;
    public ScriptingObject(WebBrowser w)
    {
        webBrowser = w;
    }
    public void Method1( string s)
    {
        //This class knows which `WebBrowser` control calls its methods.
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 1st method does not work because there is a chance that JS part will pass something else but "this" an the whole point to do not allow JS side to do fake calls.

Comment: 2nd is great :) Implemented - works like a charm. Had to rewrite some code but worth it. Thank you.

Comment: The only resource which is important to be released is the web browser control which will be released when it disposes. I cannot see any specific resource handling required for the ScriptingObject.

Comment: Great.  Thank you.